# Minimal web framework in Python for a small web application

Tags: python

I was trying to make a small and simple web application(my first one) using Google AppEngine until I hit a roadblock([Google search returns None 302 on AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726367/google-search-returns-none-302-on-appengine)) ..would appreciate if you look into this issue.

My app idea is that the user inputs a query which after some processing, a few links are recommended. There is no database or user management required in my app and hence I think Django would be an overkill. I stumbled across various other frameworks like flask, bottle, web.py etc. but could not decide which one would be the best for this simple application and for a beginner in web-dev. Suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think switching frameworks will solve your problem with urlfetch? The framework is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : True, it won't but if you read my comment to the answer in the above link, the problem is not with urlfetch. In fact I still haven't figured out what the problem is with exactly. The code worked when executed locally, but did not when deployed on Google's infrastructure. Please let me know if you are able to figure something.

Comment: Changing framworks won't solve the problem.  Stick to basic debugging and isolte which part of your code is the source of the problem, then come back with a specific question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Ok I get it now. The problem is not with the framework but the Infrastructure I am using to host the app. The fact that it worked locally means the `webapp` framework that I used did not pose any problem. Maybe I should try deploying with Heroku or Amazon and then come to any conclusion.

Comment: From the other question, I'd guess that google knows it's own, so when you try and automate searches via google from google-app-engine it just does not work. As such it's unlikely anything you try will work, or work for very long.

Answer (score 2):

Merry Xmas...
I guess the most minimalistic framework is Flask.

I have done small experiments with a few of the frameworks (Flask, Pyramid, Django, web2py...).

My personal winner is web2py (it just felt easy and elegant). I find it great in combination with pythonanywhere.com and github.com

I think it's also fair to say that you won't get away with just using Python. You will need some JavaScript and should know about css, etc.

thomas

Answer (score 1):

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) is another light-weight minimalist python web framework that you should take into consideration. In any case, any of the aforementioned minimalist frameworks would work just perfectly well for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always a supporter of Django, it just works.   I've played with Flask, CherryPy and Web2py.   Django is better than all of them, even if I just want to build something small and lightweight I'd choose Django.